# Pause TableView scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have ViewController that have a `UIView` **view** and a TableView **table** inside it. View has big height so i want to hide it when user starts to scroll table - so table is now taking the whole screen.
To do that I use this method.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //hide view or decrease it height
    }
```

I hide view with animation - so it takes few moments to hide. The problem is - when user start to scroll table and view is begin to become smaller - some of top cells of table are already not showing because they are in top.

[image]
[image]

I want to pause scrolling - so that it can begin only after the view height is decreased. Also - I am afraid that it can be strange for users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the height change as per user scroll to make it efficient.

override another delegate function

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   myView.heightConstraint = myView.originalHeight - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
```

The [contentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) property gives you the current amount of x,y scrolled in the scrollview from the origin.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, you can give your `tableView` the entire screen and make another view with whatever height you want and make it as a header view of your `tableView`. So now the view will scroll as your `tableView` scrolls. Is this what you are looking for?

```
[tableView setHeaderView:<your-custom-header-view>];
```